# struct.unpack_from in Java

Tags: java, python, binary, struct

I've got the following instruction in Python I'd like to understand and translate in Java

```
values = struct.unpack_from('>%dL' % 96, input_content, 0)
```

What does >%dL mean? 
I've checked the doc from python http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html but nothing about the percentage.
Shall I consider every returned value as a byte in Java and cast it to either double or long ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%d` is a Python string formatter similar to that found in `C`. What it says is put the thing that comes after the closing quote in place of the formatter, in this case `96` in place of `%d`. The `%d` specifies a signed integer decimal.

The `'>%dL'%96` is an instruction to `struct.unpack` to say that the thing it needs to unpack is a big endian unsigned long with an unsigned integer decimal inside it. Before the `'>%dL'` is passed to `unpack` however the string formatter is resolved and `'>%dL'` becomes `'>96L'`. Have a look at the format strings section in `struct.unpack docs

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html?highlight=struct.unpack#format-strings

Comment: @Matti: "After the QUOTE"? "The >%dL is an instruction to struct.unpack ... " -- say what? It looks like an instruction to struct.unpack to raise a bewildered exception!

Comment: @John Machin: Meant after the closing quote of the struct.unpack instruction.

Comment: @Matti: -1 It's now worse. It doesn't replace the `%d` by `%96` ... if it did, the result would be `'>%96L'`  which is NOT a valid struct format. The second `%` is an OPERATOR which causes the text substitution of `96` instead of `%d` resulting in `'>96L'`. And you haven't addressed my second point.

Comment: @John Machin: Sorry `%d` is replaced with `96` - reading the string formatting docs should've cleared your section objection but I spelled it out.

Comment: @Matti: Nobody, least of all an innocent questioner, should be required to read the docs to understand and ignore a nonsensical assertion ... which hasn't gone away, just mutated: "the thing it needs to unpack is a big endian unsigned long with an unsigned integer decimal inside it".

Answer (score 2):

The Python interactive prompt is your friend:

```
>>> '>%dL' % 96
'>96L'
>>>
```

So,

```
values = struct.unpack_from('>%dL' % 96, input_content, 0)
```

is equivalent to

```
values = struct.unpack_from('>96L', input_content, 0)
```

and the `struct` docs should tell you that '>96L' means 96 bigendian unsigned 32-bit integers.

I can't imagine why the original author wrote it in such an obfuscatory manner. It is necessary to use a technique like that to build a format if the number of items is variable, but not when it's a known constant.

Comment: ok thanks, it makes more sense, actually the original code is using a variable indeed.

Answer (score 2):

If I would write the same thing in Java it could be something like:

```
DataInputStream inputcontent = new DataInputStream(in);
long[] values = new long[96];
for (int i = 0; i < 96; i++)
    values[i] = inputcontent.readLong();
```

with the difference that the python code is using bytes that have been already loaded.

Many thanks to John Machin and Matti for their explanation.